# g++ linking issue with GSL

Tags: c++, hyperlink, g++, gsl

```
g++ -o program main.cpp classOne.cpp classTwo.cpp -lgsl -lgslblas -lm
```

that's how i compile when the GSL-packages are installed.
but now I'm working on a server where i don't have rights to install GSL-Library.
What are my options?

thx

Comment: Install it in your home directory  and give the proper linking paths. Is that also not an option ?

Comment: @DumbCoder is right, my answer is a detailed procedure how to do that, you can install a lot of other libraries you may need like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to do this regularly, do as following :

- On the server, create one directory in your home directory to install the library (let's say `mypref`) and another one to build the library (let's say `tmp`). You have two new directories : `~/mypref` and `~/tmp`.
- Download GSL sources in `~/tmp` (last version is ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.14.tar.gz), extract and go in the generated sub-directory (`gsl-1.14`) :

`cd ~/tmp`
`wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.14.tar.gz`
`tar -xvzf gsl-1.14.tar.gz`
`cd gsl-1.14`

- Launch the `configure` script specifying `~/mypref` as the installation prefix (and maybe other options depending of your server) :

`./configure --prefix=${HOME}/mypref`

- Make :

`make`

- And install :

`make install`

- Now you can remove safely the `~/tmp` directory :

`cd; rm -rf tmp`

Now you can compile your program using :

`g++ -o program main.cpp classOne.cpp classTwo.cpp -I${HOME}/mypref/include -lm -L${HOME}/mypref/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas`

`-I` and `-L` indicate respectively the path for the headers and the library. If your program is meant to be executed in a context where your home directory is not visible, consider static linking :

`g++ -o program main.cpp classOne.cpp classTwo.cpp ${HOME}/mypref/lib/libgsl.a ${HOME}/mypref/lib/libgslcblas.a -I${HOME}/mypref/include -lm`

The binary produced by the last command is bigger than previously, but entirely independent from GSL and GSLCBLAS.